# VPS SSH and my OWN IP

Tags: linux, ssh, ip, vps

Is it possible to to stay in total anonymous mode for the VPS provider?

I have got a VPSVZ machine with UBUNTU server.

Is it possible to do anonymous tunneling:

VPS1 -> VPS2 -> VPS3 (all UBUNTU) and
VPS2 provider can NOT see VPS1 IP number
AND VPS3 provider can NOT see VPS2 IP number

after I login I always see "cumentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Sun Jul 27 01:55:30 2014 from 79.124.xxxxxxx"

and i would like to stay 100% anonymous is it possible?

Comment: The remote server is going to see a client IP address. What IP addr do you want it to see?

Answer (score 1):

In order for two machines to communicate, they need to know each other's IP address. That's how they know where to send packets. You can't communicate with someone if you don't know where to send their messages.

Tunneling allows machines to communicate without knowing each other's IP address by embedding packets inside another communication layer and using one or more intermediate machines as relays. Think of it as putting an envelope inside another envelope and asking the recipient of the outer envelope to re-send the envelope found inside (given that communication is bidirectional, all envelopes must have a return address, and the relay will forward traffic in the other direction).

In your configuration, you can arrange for VPS3 not to know anything about VPS1, but VPS1 and VPS2 have to know each other, as do VPS2 and VPS3.

If you want anonymity, you can use [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)). Tor is a long chain of relays, and its security rests upon the fact that the relays don't collaborate much, so that even someone who controls relays #32 and #31 won't know who you are because relay #30 won't share. How to set up Tor is beyond the scope of this answer; there are tutorials on the web.

Be aware that true anonymity is very hard: it's very easy to slip up. If you hide your IP address and then accidentally type your real name in a form, you've lost your anonymity.